# Dynamically change dropdowns via SQL and calculate sums?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I've got a row in a table with 3 fields laid out as so:

```
Job            Pay Grade       Cost
<Select>       <Select>        <Calculation>
```

I've got an SQL table with the information above in it, for example:

```
Job            Pay Grade       Cost
Techie         1               100
Techie         2               200
Engi           2               300
Engi           3               400
Engi           4               500
```

What I need to do is to be able to select a Job from the dropdown and then the Pay Grade select box will change depending on what matches that job in the SQL database.   It will then show the cost which relates to the to selected.

How can I go about this as I am a little stuck

Comment: Did you look at javascript, jquery or ajax? or You might need to tell what is the roadblock that is where you are stuck at?

Comment: There are many options to do so. One is to use a form and submit it. Then, get outputs from SQL queries. Second is to use ajax to listen to events (get dropdown value) and then submit the value to SQL query.

Comment: I've havent actually started anything as I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the select job via $.ajax and then in success function populate the dropdown list like this:

```
function selectHandler (event, ui)
        {
        var id = event.target.id;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/php/get_quantity_type.php",
                dataType:"json",
                data: { ingridient : ui.item.value},
                success: function(data){$("#"+id+"_t").empty(); $.each(data,function(index,value) {$("#"+id+"_t").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');})}
                });
        }
```

This example takes a name of a material from select list posts it via $ajax() to a php script and writes it down to a new dropdown list which id is based on id that triggered the event. If you need the php code just ask:)

You bind your job list to the event handler above:

```
("#job_list").bind("select",selectHandler);
```

This code posts data to "/php/get_quantity_type.php", and passess the result to function declared in success attribute;

Comment: Thanks - however I am a little unclear of how to get my Job dropdown to post to the function and then generate the contents of the grade dropdown

Answer (score 1):

First create ajax request when a job title is selected. WIthin the success callback of the request will generate html for the options for pay grade select from JSON response from server

jQuery

```
$('select.jobTitle').change(function(){
    var $titleSelect=$(this);
    $.getJSON('processJobGrades.php', { jobTitle : $(this).val() }, function(response){
        var gradesOptionsHtml=''; 
        /* create options html from json response */
        $.each( response, function(i, item){
            gradesOptionsHtml+='<option value="'+item.grade+' data-cost="'+item.cost+'">'+item.grade+'</option>';
        });  
         $titleSelect.parent().find('select.jobGrade').html(gradesOptionsHtml);       
    });   
});
```

IN `processJobGrades.php` receive `$_GET['jobTitle']` . Do DB lookup and create json to send back.

PHP

```
$outputArray=array();

/*in loop over DB data:*/
$outputArray[]= array( 'grade'=>$row['grade'], 'cost'=>$row['cost']);

/*Output final array as JSON*/
echo json_encode( $outputArray);
```

jQuery  change handler for paygrade select to get `cost`

```
$('select.jobGrade').change(function(){
     var cost=$(this).find(':selected').data('cost')
     $(this).parent().find('input.jobCost').val( cost);
})
```

Comment: Thanks but not sure how this helps me?  I need 2 dropdowns, 1 which is the job and then the pay grade which changes depending on the job

Comment: OK.. I missed the duplicate job titles in example. Will work up ajax solution

Comment: Wow brilliant.  Let me try it out and i'll get back

Comment: fixed a couple of syntax typos